# How do I access the internet with an infected computer that WILL NOT let me?

Tags: virus, malware

I`m trying to fix my friend`s Toshiba laptop. She has Windows 7, no anti-virus and is infected with a virus. The computer shows no connection problems; but I cannot access the internet or download a disc to clean it up. I want to use esetnod32 and malwarebytes. I`m not as tech savvy as most of you, but I can hold my own.
Melissa.

Comment: Your motivation to fix it is admirable. However, removing malware is by no means feasible.

Comment: If you go into safe mode with internet, you should be able to operate. Keep tapping F8 after power-on. You can also start an on-line scan from here: http://www.bitdefender.com/scanner/online/free.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a USB drive to transfer any data to the infected machine! Or you risk an infection of the USB drive and any other workstation you use it with. It is safer to use a CD for transfer.

I think the best way is to use a LINUX System, running by CD or USB drive like AVIRA-Rescue-Disc

http://www.avira.com/de/download/product/avira-rescue-system

Comment: Please do not add signatures to your posts. From http://superuser.com/help/behavior "Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings."